# Input into Characters

Tags: c#, input, int

Question is I have to make a console application where i input a number and it writes out symbol "|" as many i inserted. Example if i insert number 6 it writes out ||||||. And it keeps asking until I insert 0 and it closes. So far the input has been made like this :

```
int input;

Console.Write("\n\n Insert an number ---> ");
input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

I have tried with char array but no use.

Comment: Well, how far did you get with the char array approach? What did your code look like? At the moment it just sounds like you want us to do your homework for you...

Comment: Did you read the chapter `Loops` ?

Comment: I would probably go with a loop

Comment: try to use Integer.TryParse instead, your teacher will like you

Comment: and what if the input is not a valid integer?

Answer (score 3):

There is actually [a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) on `string` that initializes a string with the given character a certain number of times:

`string s = new string('|', 10);`

`s` will be the string `"||||||||||"`

Answer (score 2):

Loops are so 2012 :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)
      .Select(i => Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i) ? i : -1)
      .Where(i => i >= 0)
      .TakeWhile(i => i > 0)
      .Select(i => {
         Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("|", i)));
         return 0;})
      .Count();
  }
}
```

Description (even the answer is very non-serious):

- `Enumerable.Range` is to allow semi-infinite (as Chris Sinclair pointed out it is only 2,147,483,647 times) enumerable to have most of the code in single statement.
- First `Select` reads input line by line and convert valid input to integers, the rest to -1 (note that in this sample -1 is possible value for "invalid input", normally one would return `Tuple<int, bool>` or `int?` to signify invalid values
- `Where` filters out "invalid" inputs (correctly entered negative numbers as well all non-numbers that where reported as -1 by previous `Select`).
- `TakeWhile` provides termination condition for 0.
- Second `Select` prints result. Note that to construct string from multiple copies of the same character one should use proper `new String("|", count)` constructor, but it less fun.
- finally `Count` forces immediate iteration of the query.

Comment: But but... this will only run 2,147,483,647 times!

Comment: @SamIam - I've updated (not very serious) answer with complete code. As you suggested resulting enumerable need to be iterated to actually do something.

Comment: @Fredou, adding try parse did not endup looking too bad... So here it is.

Comment: This is amusing right up until somebody winds up supporting it in production.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It wasn't the fact that it was not a complete program so much as that it didn't actually work the first time.  it works now though.

Comment: @SamIam - I know - thanks for trying out! It was missing "force iteration" part - works fine in LinqPad since it iterates all enumerable to display them, but obviously was not complete sample - `.Count()` - is the simplest way to force iteartion (and does not produce much garbage), I was thinking about using Aggregate instead but it would be way too much fun.

Comment: You can actually remove the `int value` holder for the `TryParse` and use the `_` lambda input parameter instead: `.Select(_ => Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out _) ? _ : -1)` (you know, to make it more fun!)

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

```
 is read line a number
   until read line is 0
       for 1 to the number
           print |
     is read line a number
     if not a number go back at asking the number saying it is not a number
 if not a number go back at asking the number saying it is not a number
```

now have fun doing your homework

Answer (score 0):

tow basic concepts you should know

**the for loop:**

```
for(int i=0; i<input; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is a common patter for doing something `input` times, so if `input` is equal to `6`, than it will `//do stuff` 6 times.

---

**Console.Write**

```
Console.Write('|');
```

`Console.Write` writes the text to the console **without** adding adding a new line at the end.

---

I'm sure that you can combine some of these language features somehow, to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used that and used Do While loop. :)